# Summarize one variable/column over all possible values of other variables/columns

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I need to summarize one variable/column of a long table after aggregating (group_by()) by another variable/column, I need to have the summarized value by all values of other variables/columns.

Here is test data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

Site <- str_c("S", 1:5)
Species <- str_c("Sps", 1:6)

print(Species_tbl <- bind_cols(Species = Species,
                        Exotic = rbinom(length(Species), 1, .3),
                        Migrant = rbinom(length(Species), 2, .3)))


Data_tbl <- expand.grid(Site = Site,
                        Species = Species) %>%
            left_join(Species_tbl)


Data_tbl$Presence <- rbinom(nrow(Data_tbl), 1, .5)
```

And here is my best effort:

```
print(Data_tbl %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarise(N_sp = sum(Presence),
            N_sp_Exo = sum(Presence[Exotic == 1]),
            N_sp_Nat = sum(Presence[Exotic == 0]),
            N_sp_M0 = sum(Presence[Migrant == 0]),
            N_sp_M1 = sum(Presence[Migrant == 1]),
            N_sp_M2 = sum(Presence[Migrant == 2])))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the data in long format for your columns of interest `c(Exotic, Migrant)` and take `sum` of `Presence` columns for each unique column names and it's values. This can be merged with `sum` of each `Site`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 <- Data_tbl %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarise(N_sp = sum(Presence))

data2 <- Data_tbl %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Exotic, Migrant)) %>%
  group_by(Site, name, value) %>%
  summarise(result = sum(Presence), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, value), values_from = result)

inner_join(data1, data2, by = 'Site')

#  Site   N_sp Exotic_0 Exotic_1 Migrant_0 Migrant_1 Migrant_2
#  <fct> <int>    <int>    <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
#1 S1        4        2        2         1         2         1
#2 S2        3        2        1         0         2         1
#3 S3        2        1        1         0         2         0
#4 S4        4        2        2         1         3         0
#5 S5        4        1        3         1         2         1
```

The answer has been divided in two steps for ease of readability. If you would like to do this in a single chain without creating temporary variables that can be done as well.